# I got this error in python TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-docx

I have a code that is supposed to take a link from a docx file and download it , The name of the file in witch the code is supposed to take the link from is One.docx. And than i have "take = doc.paragraphs[0].text " witch is supposed to take the first link from the docx file. But it gives my the  "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable." error. Here is my code

```
import docx

name_of_file = "One.docx" 
doc = docx.Document(name_of_file)
take = doc.paragraphs[0].text

url = print(take)[:-1]+".json"
```

Comment: Why do you have a `print` call in there? `print` returns `None`. Do you mean just `url = take[:-1]+".json"`?

Comment: Post the traceback message which includes the failing line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is produced by the last line because `print(stuff)` returns `None`, so `print(stuff)[other stuff]` is invalid. `print` should not be in your last line at all if you are trying to construct a url string from another string.